# Smoke sim does not render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

The smoke sim I made shows up in every viewport besides render, and it does not show up when I render image. I tried recreating the flow and domain, switching cycles to evee and back.

https://pasteall.org/blend/d2f16ddaf38a461483c8c8ece0f67571 .blend file

Comment: although i personally love if people provide blend files, you should also provide some screenshots what you have done because often with this we can help you even faster (without downloading and checking your blend file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your domain has no material.

Add this material to your domain, and you get this result in render:

[image]